# Numpy element wise "between" comparison

Tags: numpy

I have an array a, and want to do element-wise comparisons of whether every element of a is between a * 0.5 and a * 1.5.

Ignoring the fact that this will obviously be true by construction, is there an operator in numpy that I can use to do this? Something like `np.less_than` or `np.greater_than`?

I originally tried using

```
np.logical_or(a * 0.9 <= a, a <= a * 1.1)
```

but that doesn't work when there are negative values.

```
a = np.array([
       [[ 0.08537571, -0.0067365 , -0.01217636],
        [-0.0067365 ,  0.02299117,  0.01799304],
        [-0.01217636,  0.01799304,  0.02048184]],

       [[ 0.10117361,  0.07530722,  0.02475461],
        [ 0.07530722,  0.06585286,  0.02021006],
        [ 0.02475461,  0.02021006,  0.01555354]],

       [[ 0.0310301 ,  0.03208571,  0.02354831],
        [ 0.03208571,  0.03584655,  0.03389133],
        [ 0.02354831,  0.03389133,  0.08047313]],

       [[ 0.00012582,  0.00047486,  0.00037565],
        [ 0.00047486,  0.02343885,  0.01601785],
        [ 0.00037565,  0.01601785,  0.02085996]]])
```

Comment: "doesn't work when there are negative values" based on the definition of your condition, isn't it correct that that doesn't work? Or do you mean to compare the magnitude only?

Comment: @coldspeed Oh, I see what you mean. The signs have to be reversed for negative values, so perhaps I do have to compare the magnitudes.

Comment: Something like `(x<=a) != (y<=a)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
np.logical_or(abs(a) * 0.9 <= abs(a), abs(a) <= abs(a) * 1.1)
```

Tweaking your code to include abs() will compare the magnitude only.